# IS there any way i can make this shorter

Tags: c#, scripting, unity-game-engine

I am learning how to use untiy in my spare time by reading a beginners book and looking up stuff online in the book there is a exercise that asks me

> to create a script that outputs the numbers from 1 to 10 in to the console but dose not output any multiple of 3 and 5 instead outputting the phrase "programming is awesome "

while i have achieved this task by using this code

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class Loops : MonoBehaviour {

// Use this for initialization
void Start () {

    for(int i = 1; i <= 10; i++)
    {
        if(i == 3 )
            print ("Programming is Awesome!");
        else if (i == 5)
            print ("Programming is Awesome!");
        else if (i == 6)
            print ("Programming is Awesome!");
        else if (i == 9)
            print ("Programming is Awesome!");
        else if (i == 10)
            print ("Programming is Awesome!");
        else
            print (i);
    }
}


}
```

i was wondering if there was any way to achieve the same result only by using less lines of code

Comment: Heh.. Unity's version of FizzBuzz. Love it. Code review is probably a better place for this.

Comment: Can you do this is Unity? `Enumerable.Range(1, 100).FirstOrDefault(m => { print(m % 5 == 0 ? "programming is awesome" : m % 3 == 0 ? "programming is awesome" : m.ToString()); return false;});` Don't know why you'd ever do it but its shorter :p

Answer (score 1):

You want to use the modulus (aka modulo) operator (%) for this task. It returns the remainder of a division, so when the result of a modulus operation is 0 you know you have a multiple of the divisor.

```
for (int i = 1; i <= 10; i++)
{
    if(i % 3 == 0 || i % 5 == 0)
        print("programming is awesome");
    else
        print(i);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The point of this exercise is that you should calculate the multiples, not just make one condition for every value that you know is a multiple.

Use the modulo operator to check it a number is an even multiple of another. This shows what the modulo operator returns for some values:

```
 i    i % 3
------------
 1      1
 2      2
 3      0
 4      1
 5      2
 6      0
 7      1
```

As you see, `i % 3` evaluates to `0` when `i` is a multiple of three. You can use that to check if the number is a multiple of three:

```
if (i % 3 == 0) {
  print ("Programming is Awesome!");
}
```

Now you should be able to do the same for five also, and incorporate it in your code.

Answer (score 1):

```
  for (int i = 1; i <= 10; i++)
        {
            print((i % 3 == 0 || i % 5 == 0)? "programming is awesome" : i));
        }
```

check out also using ternary operator.

Answer (score 0):

Ways of doing this

```
if(i == 3 || i == 5 || i == 6 || i == 9 || i == 10){
    print ("Programming is Awesome!");
}
else {
    print (i);
}
```

**Better way** By Using the modulo operator

```
if( i % 3 == 0 || i % 5 == 0){
    print ("Programming is Awesome!");
}
else {
    print (i);
}
```

Use can also try

```
print((i % 3 == 0 || i % 5 == 0)? "Programming is Awesome!" : i));
```